# How to compare two spinner values to display toast & change one spinner value

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-widget, android-spinner

i want to display a toast when two spinner values are same, and revert back spinner1 value back to its default value from being same with spinner two

here is my java code

```
    package com.test16.sp2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

    public class Test16sp2Activity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Spinner spin1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            Spinner spin2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Planet_array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Planet_array2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spin1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
            spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
        }
        public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
            Spinner spin1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            Spinner spin2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
                if(spin1==spin2)
                {
              Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "your source and destination are same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
              // Do nothing.
             }
            }
            }
```

rest all files are same as android developer's planet example http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the Spinners, not the Spinner values.  Look at the properties of the `spin1` and `spin2` variables, you should find something along the lines of a `.getSelected()`